# Invoking bash script via KB shortcut in KDE won't run all commands from the script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, kde-plasma

I'm new to bash scripting and need help knowing how to debug this.

This is a TTS script that uses the `espek` TTS engine to speak the contents of `xsel`
which holds the contents of whatever the user has highlighted with their cursor.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ $(pgrep espeak) ]; then
    killall espeak;
else
    espeak "$(xsel)";
fi
```

The script runs fine when invoked from the terminal `./tts_script.sh`.  The issue is when I try to invoke it from the keyboard shortcut that I set up in KDE.

I set up the shortcut like this...

- go to "System Settings>>Shortcuts>>Custom Shortcuts"
- selected "Edit>>New>>Global Shortcut>>Command/URL"
- chose a keyboard trigger
- then under the action tab I put `~/scripts/tts_script.sh`

I tested it by including the following line of code in the top

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
espeak "hello there";
```

I invoked the script with the shortcut and it does speak "hello there" but that's it.
I was able to determine that when the script is invoked from the shortcut it fails as soon as it encounters anything to do with `xsel`.

- Are there any debug logs I can look into?
- Are there alternative ways I can invoke the script?
- Are there alternative ways I can set a keyboard shortcut in KDE?
- Is my code total garbage that makes no sense at all?

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `xclip` instead of `xsel` solved the problem

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ $(pidof espeak) ]; then
    killall espeak;
else
    espeak "$(xclip -selection primary -o)";
fi
```